# Is there any API for creating custom server roles in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-server-2008, roles, windows-server

Subject is self-explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is. The Server Roles in windows are used for adding additional *Windows* components onto the core operating system. To get any other, third party, components onto a server, you're going to run an installation of some kind. And typically, during such an installation, you'll choose which components of the software package you wish to install (if not all).

I certainly wouldn't expect to install a software package, only to then have to use a further mechanism to "enable" what I've already installed. And if I want to change which components of the software package are installed/enabled, I expect to change those through the usual add/remove programs or re-running the installer.